# Circularly Magnetized Neodymium Torus With Minimum Flux Leakage

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetostatics

I'd like to conduct some experiments related to Aharonov-Bohm.  In particular, I'd like to investigate the irrotational vector potential gradient.  A simple geometry for this is the major axis of a toroidal field:

[image]

Rather than a current sheet, I'd prefer a very strong permanent magnetic torus with minimum flux leakage.  Neodymium alloy seems ideal in terms of strength but fabrication is problematic given its material properties.  If very low flux leakage were attainable with the minor cross-section rectangular rather than circular, would it be reasonable to buy a "ring" magnet off the shelf, poloidally wrap it with conductive wire, heat it to well above the Curie temperature and then zap it with a powerful current discharge from a supercapacitor to realign the domains in the circular direction?

PS:  I have inquired about having one of these custom made but the response from folks advertising custom magnets is "can't do".

Comment: A supercapacitor won't give you a strong current. Use an ordinary capacitor, instead. A permanent magnet won't give you good control over the field. Do you really need such a string field? If you want to build something like that, machine a small permanent magnet into a soft iron torus. Effective shielding of a magnetic field can be done with multiple layers of magnetic material with gaps and, maybe, a current layer to tune to zero field. That's a much cleaner solution than trying to optimize material properties.

Comment: So am I to take your response as implying a sustained current, while cooling below the Curie temperature to anneal the field lines isn't as important an instantaneously higher current above the Curie temperature?

Comment: No... my comment had nothing to do with that. I was pointing out that supercapacitors are lousy capacitors, that permanent magnetism is a pain in the bum if you need control over the field (which such an experiment should have for obvious reasons) and that eliminating a magnetic field to near zero requires multiple lines of attack, while you are trying to do it with only one  method.